# Get first child of the first child of each element in an array

Tags: javascript

I've built an array of `table` elements matching a specific criterion using `querySelectorAll()`, but I'd like to conditionally create a new, separate array containing the first child of the first child of each of those elements.
However, I'm not sure how to do this.
My array currently looks like this:

```
var arr = [
    <table class="matchedCriterion">…</table>,
    <table class="matchedCriterion">…</table>
];
```

Is there a way for me to run `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` on each element, matching what I want using `:first-child:first-child`

Comment: Are you using [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X)?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I don't believe so.

Comment: Ok.  So the `<table …>`s embedded in your JS code sample are not meant to be interpreted as literal JS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.map` function lets you build a new Array from another array.

```
var newarr = arr.map(function(el) { return el.firstChild.firstChild; });
```

If your `arr` is not actually an array, then do this.

```
var newarr = [].map.call(arr, function(el) { return el.firstChild.firstChild; });
```

Be aware that this will get text nodes if those happen to be the first child. If you want elements only, use `.firstElementChild` instead of `.firstChild`.

Comment: for the second part, there is another way: `Array.from(arr).map(callback)`, which does the same with sugar syntax.